# Hyperledger Fabric: How are conflicts between differing copies of the ledger resolved?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In case of Bitcoin (and Proof of Work in general) there is a simple rule that provides automatic conflict resolution when there are 2 differing copies of the ledger for any reason. And that rule is the longer chain wins.

But how are conflicts resolved in case of Fabric? Saying that conflicts never occur in Fabric is not an answer because if conflicts never occur, then what is the purpose of getting endorsement from more than one peer?

Stating alternatively, if your answer is that conflicts never occur in Fabric, then please explain why would someone want to get endorsement from more than one peer?

Yet another way to frame this question: let's say the copy of the ledger hosted on the peer of another organization got hacked unbeknownst to them. Now your organization and the other organization have different records. How will the conflict be reconciled? And don't forget the havoc this will cause - all transactions submitted by users will now fail to get endorsement until the conflict is resolved. A hack on another organization disrupted your business even though your ledger was not compromised.

Answer (score 1):

In Proof of work:

Client will submit a transaction and it will be in pool, any miner can take and validate the transaction and then do mining, if he get solved quickly then he will publish to other miners. Here many nodes involved in Orderer to create a block

In Hyperledger Fabric [HighLevel]:

Client send transaction to endorsing peers(more than one), endorsing peers will sent back R/W and signatures to client, if endorsement failed means data in consistency then it will mark as failed and sent back to client.

Client will send entire payload to Orderer. Orderer simply creates a block and ship to committing peers, committing peers simply very endorsements (more than one ) and commit to the ledger

No tell me by comparing both, do u think still conflicts will come in hyperledger fabric?

Purpose of getting endorsement: In order to authentic more endorsements more accurate.

**LowLevel**:

Stage 1: [CLient Initiate Tx]

> Client A is sending a request to update the ledger.
>   This request targets peerA and peerB, who are respectively
>   representative of Client A and Client B. The endorsement policy states
>   that both peers must endorse any transaction, therefore the request
>   goes to peerA and peerB.

Stage 2: Endorsing peers verify signature & execute the transaction

> The endorsing peers verify (1) that the transaction proposal is well
>   formed, (2) it has not been submitted already in the past
>   (replay-attack protection), (3) the signature is valid (using the
>   MSP), and (4) that the submitter (Client A, in the example) is
>   properly authorized to perform the proposed operation on that channel
>   (namely, each endorsing peer ensures that the submitter satisfies the
>   channel’s Writers policy). The endorsing peers take the transaction
>   proposal inputs as arguments to the invoked chaincode’s function. The
>   chaincode is then executed against the current state database to
>   produce transaction results including a response value, read set, and
>   write set (i.e. key/value pairs representing an asset to create or
>   update). No updates are made to the ledger at this point. The set of
>   these values, along with the endorsing peer’s signature is passed back
>   as a “proposal response” to the SDK which parses the payload for the
>   application to consume.

Stage 3: Client Proposal responses are inspected

> The application verifies the endorsing peer signatures and compares
>   the proposal responses to determine if the proposal responses are the
>   same. If the chaincode is only queried the ledger, the application
>   would inspect the query response and would typically not submit the
>   transaction to the ordering service. If the client application intends
>   to submit the transaction to the ordering service to update the
>   ledger, the application determines if the specified endorsement policy
>   has been fulfilled before submitting (i.e. did peerA and peerB both
>   endorse). The architecture is such that even if an application chooses
>   not to inspect responses or otherwise forwards an unendorsed
>   transaction, the endorsement policy will still be enforced by peers
>   and upheld at the commit validation phase.

Stage 4 : Client assembles endorsements into a transaction and broadcast

> The application “broadcasts” the transaction proposal and response
>   within a “transaction message” to the ordering service. The
>   transaction will contain the read/write sets, the endorsing peers
>   signatures and the Channel ID. The ordering service does not need to
>   inspect the entire content of a transaction in order to perform its
>   operation, it simply receives transactions from all channels in the
>   network, orders them chronologically by channel, and creates blocks of
>   transactions per channel.

Stage 5: Transaction is validated and committed

> The blocks of transactions are “delivered” to all peers on the
>   channel. The transactions within the block are validated to ensure
>   endorsement policy is fulfilled and to ensure that there have been no
>   changes to ledger state for read set variables since the read set was
>   generated by the transaction execution. Transactions in the block are
>   tagged as being valid or invalid.

Stage 6: Ledger updated

> Each peer appends the block to the channel’s chain, and for each valid
>   transaction the write sets are committed to current state database. An
>   event is emitted, to notify the client application that the
>   transaction (invocation) has been immutably appended to the chain, as
>   well as notification of whether the transaction was validated or
>   invalidated.